# difference between %ms and %s scanf

Tags: c, gcc, glibc, scanf

Reading the `scanf` manual I encounter this line:

> An optional 'm' character.  This is used with string conversions
> (`%s`, `%c`, `%[`),

Can someone explain it with simple example stating the difference and the need of such an option in some cases?

Comment: Do you think I only read the first line only ?! -_-  I did not understand it honestly ! that's why I just wanted a tiny example with simple explanation stating the difference with simple words ?

Comment: 1) `char word[32]; scanf("%31s", word);/* The maximum number of characters in the input is known. */`

Comment: 2) `char *word; scanf("%ms", &word);/* input size is unknown. dynamically allocated according to the input. */`

Comment: I hate to sound harsh but this is an impression your question leaves. The paragraph explains the difference quite well. If you didn't understand a specific phrase why not mention it?

Comment: I am still a beginner in C and I am doing my best to understand it quite well. I hate reading sthg and just skip it like that ! I really appreciate that ! thanks a lot @BLUEPIXY

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The C Standard does not define such an optional character in the `scanf()` formats.

The GNU lib C, does define an optional `a` indicator this way (from the man page for `scanf`):

> An optional `a` character. This is used with string conversions, and relieves the caller of the need to allocate a corresponding  buffer to hold the input: instead, `scanf()` allocates a buffer of sufficient size, and assigns the address of this buffer to the corresponding  pointer argument, which should be a pointer to a `char *` variable (this variable does not need to  be initialized  before  the  call).
>
> The caller should subsequently `free` this buffer when it is no longer required. This  is  a GNU  extension;  C99  employs  the `a` character as a conversion specifier (and it can also be used as such in the GNU  implementation).

The **NOTES** section of the man page says:

> The `a` modifier is not available if the program is compiled with `gcc -std=c99` or `gcc -D_ISOC99_SOURCE` (unless  `_GNU_SOURCE`  is  also specified),  in which case the `a` is interpreted as a specifier for floating-point numbers (see above).
>
> Since version 2.7, glibc also provides the `m` modifier for the same purpose as the a modifier.  The `m` modifier has the following advantages:
>
> - It may also be applied to `%c` conversion specifiers (e.g., `%3mc`).
> - It  avoids ambiguity with respect to the `%a` floating-point conversion specifier (and is unaffected by `gcc -std=c99` etc.)
> - It is specified in the upcoming revision of the POSIX.1 standard.

The online linux manual page at  http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf only documents this option as:

> An optional 'm' character. This is used with string conversions (`%s`, `%c`, `%[`), and relieves the caller of the need to allocate a corresponding buffer to hold the input: instead, `scanf()` allocates a buffer of sufficient size, and assigns the address of this buffer to the corresponding pointer argument, which should be a pointer to a `char *` variable (this variable does not need to be initialized before the call). The caller should subsequently `free(3)` this buffer when it is no longer required.

The Posix standard documents this extension in its POSIX.1-2008 edition (see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html ):

> The `%c`, `%s`, and `%[` conversion specifiers shall accept an optional assignment-allocation character `m`, which shall cause a memory buffer to be allocated to hold the string converted including a terminating null character. In such a case, the argument corresponding to the conversion specifier should be a reference to a pointer variable that will receive a pointer to the allocated buffer. The system shall allocate a buffer as if `malloc()` had been called. The application shall be responsible for freeing the memory after usage. If there is insufficient memory to allocate a buffer, the function shall set `errno` to [`ENOMEM`] and a conversion error shall result. If the function returns `EOF`, any memory successfully allocated for parameters using assignment-allocation character `m` by this call shall be freed before the function returns.

Using this extension, you could write:

```
char *p;
scanf("%ms", &p);
```

Causing `scanf` to parse a word from standard input and allocate enough memory to store its characters plus a terminating `'\0'`.  A pointer to the allocated array would be stored into `p` and `scanf()` would return `1`, unless no non whitespace characters can be read from `stdin`.

It is entirely possible that other systems use `m` for similar semantics or for something else entirely.  Non-standard extensions are non portable and should be used very carefully, documented as such, in circumstances where a standard approach is cumbersome impractical or altogether impossible.

Note that parsing a word of arbitrary size is indeed impossible with the standard version of `scanf()`:

You can parse a word with a maximum size and should specify the maximum number of characters to store before the `'\0'`:

```
char buffer[20];
scanf("%19s", buffer);
```

But this does not tell you how many more characters are available to parse in standard input.  In any case, not passing the maximum number of characters may invoke undefined behavior if the input is long enough, and specially crafted input may even be used by an attacker to compromise your program:

```
char buffer[20];
scanf("%s", buffer); // potential undefined behavior,
                     // that could be exploited by an attacker.
```

Comment: It's part of the POSIX 2013 standard -- so any system that conforms to that standard will support it.

Comment: Its accessable online [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html)