# How can I use a character pointer and input a string into it?

Tags: c, scanf

Is there any way I can do this **without** using dynamic memory allocation?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char* str = NULL;
    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

Comment: Yes you can use static allocation, e.g. `char str[100];`

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/166737)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no straightforward way as per the `C` standard (`C11`), however, [POSIX defines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html) optional assignment-allocation character `m` as part of the conversion specifier, which relives the programmer from the responsibility of allocating memory.

However, under the hood, this does use dynamic memory allocation, and you need to call `free()` on the pointer later on.

Quoting the reference:

> The `%c`, `%s`, and `%[` conversion specifiers shall accept an optional assignment-allocation character `'m'`, which shall cause a memory buffer to be allocated to hold the string converted including a terminating null character. In such a case, the argument corresponding to the conversion specifier should be a reference to a pointer variable that will receive a pointer to the allocated buffer. The system shall allocate a buffer as if `malloc()` had been called. The application shall be responsible for freeing the memory after usage. If there is insufficient memory to allocate a buffer, the function shall set `errno` to `[ENOMEM]` and a conversion error shall result. If the function returns `EOF`, any memory successfully allocated for parameters using assignment-allocation character `'m'` by this call shall be freed before the function returns.

Something like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char* str = NULL;
    scanf("%ms", &str);
    printf("%s\n", str);
    free(str);

    return 0;
}
```

would do the job.

Comment: `GNU lib C` also defines _[such a feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38686325/645128)_.

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
int main()
{
  char str[100];
  scanf("%s", str);
  printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

Comment: What if the user enters a hundred or more characters?

Comment: @ryyker Well after the question title, the OP asks for a solution _without using dynamic memory allocation?_ so...

Comment: The answer by Sourav is neat, but still uses dynamic memory allocation under the hood.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, but you are going to waste memory, or have the risk of  segmentanltion violation:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main() { 
     char str[512] = {0} // as suggested by Jabberwocky
     //sprintf(str, "");
     //scanf("%s", str); // protecting the input from more than 511 chars
     scanf("%511s", str);
     printf("%s\n", str); 
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the risk? Is there any workaround? Perhaps another function that could be called to enter the string?

Comment: Why `sprintf(str, "");`? Why not `str[0] = 0;` or `char str[512] = {0};`. And what if the user enters a string longer than 511 characters?

Comment: So restrict the input from scanf to a fixed number of characters. Or preferably use fgets. Or better yet, forget about using stdio.h.

Comment: If the input is greater than the "buffer size" (say, 511 characters + ending \0) you are going to try to access memory that was not allocated to your process, and a SEGV (segmentation violation) will occur. You can limit the input, using `scanf("%511s", str);`

Comment: the idiom `sprintf(str, "");` or the suggested `str[0] = 0` are unneccessary in this particular piece of code; in any case, the `sprintf` version seems easier to understand. Regarding the limiting, I have updated my suggested answer.