# Is there a way to create a gender evaluation

Tags: c

I'm trying to get the user of a C program to Enter M for Male and F for Female
and to loop through if it doesn't meet M or F .
Below I have tried the following code but it loops twice giving the correct answer.
For instance after entering M it loops and  prints

FALSE gender .. please enter M for Male and M for 
           Female

is there any way to solve it .

The goal is if the user enter M or F it will work without needing to enter it a second time.
if anything else it may ask a number of times

```
 #include "Gender.h"
 #include<stdio.h>


  char sex;
  void Gender(){

  printf("\nEnter Student Gender ('example M for Male  F for Female):\n");

  scanf(" %s",&sex);



      while (sex != "M" || sex != "M"){
       printf ("\n FALSE gender .. please enter M for Male and M for Female:\n");
        scanf(" %s",&sex);
        printf("\nStudent Sex :%c", sex,"\n");
        return;
      }


  }
```

Comment: The expression in the `while` statement is checking `"M"` twice. Also, to compare strings in C, use the `strcmp` function.

Comment: And use `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: `"%s"` consumes leading whitespace, so the space in `" %s"` is not needed -- HOWEVER, you do not check the return (ignoring a manual `EOF`) and you fail to remove any extraneous characters beyond the first character (e.g. after reading `sex`, `int c = getchar(); while (c != '\n' && c != EOF) c = getchar();`) This beyond your mismatch in types between `char sex` and `"%s"` expecting a pointer to char with sufficient storage to hold the string (including the *nul-terminating* character)

Comment: **M** for Male and **M** for Female (inside the loop)?  I think the ladies are entitled to feel annoyed.  The `return` inside the loop means that people get one retry, which isn't tested.  You also throw away the result of the user's input — that's not very good.  Surely you should return the selected gender?  It might be worth adding a count on the retries and stopping people from going into a loop.  Stop after 10 failed attempts, for example.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I now realize my typo but still when i change the F for female it still does the same thing.

Comment: Can I downvote the instructor who assigned this?

Answer (score 5):

`sex` is a single `char` variable, but you are treating it as a pointer to a string.

1. Change your `scanf` call to have `%c` (single character) in the format string, rather than `%s`.
2. Change your tests for the value of `sex` to use single quotes (i.e. `if (sex == 'M')`).

Note that though this code *should not need* string comparison if the variable `sex` is treated like the single `char` it is, if you were to compare strings in a future project, you would not use the operators `==` and `!=` - instead, use the function [`strcmp`](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/string.h/strcmp) in `<string.h>`

Comment: Should point out when the user does enter something that is not M or F then you should read up to the new line character and dispose of that data in the stream

Answer (score 1):

Several things, I've provided an implementation with comments...

Include `ctype.h` to use toupper(3) and allow both upper and lower case entry.
You can either use character comparison, or string comparison, I gave you both, pick one.

```
#include "Gender.h"
#include <stdio.h>

//you should really define these in your Gender.h file...
#define MALE "M"
#define FEMALE "F"
//you should really define these in your Gender.h file...
static const char* GenderAllowed = MALE" for Male and "FEMALE" for Female";
static const char* GenderPrompt = "Enter Student Gender";

//compare as string[1] - keep either this
#include <string.h>
int sexValidc( char* sex ) {
    return ( (0==strncmp(sex,MALE,1)) || (0==strncmp(sex,FEMALE,1)) );
}

//compare only first character - or keep this
#include <ctype.h>
int sexValids( char* sex ) {
    char sexch = toupper(*sex); //fold first character to upper case
    return ( (*MALE==sexch) || (*FEMALE==sexch) );
}

char Gender() {
    char sex[69+1]; //since you wanted to use %s, need a buffer, your &char allows stack overflow & wild memory pointer-ing
    printf("\n%s (%s):\n",GenderPrompt,GenderAllowed); //DRY - Dont Repeat Yourself...
    int done = 0;
    while( !done ) {
        scanf(" %69s",sex); //avoid stackoverflow :-)
        if( !sexValidc( sex ) ) {
//printf("blech, entered: %s\n",sex); //debugging, remove when comfortable
            printf("\n FALSE gender .. %s %s:\n",GenderPrompt,GenderAllowed);
        }
        else { //valid
            done = 1;
        }
    }
    printf("\nStudent Sex :%c\n", *sex);
    return *sex; //once you enter valid value, return it...
}

int main() {
    Gender();
}
```

Also read this about automatic allocation of buffer space, [difference between %ms and %s scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38685724/difference-between-ms-and-s-scanf)

Comment: I am trying it this way

char sex;

void Gender(){

    printf("\nEnter Student Gender (example M for Male  F for Female):\n");

    scanf(" %c",&sex);



  switch(sex){
  case 'M':
  case 'm':
    printf("Student Sex : Male");
    break;
  case 'F':
  case 'f':
    printf("Student Sex : Female");
    break;

  default:
    printf("\n FALSE gender .. please enter M for Male and F for Female:\n");


}



}

Comment: You gotta use only one of the sexValid functions - I've changed the names to end in 'c' and 's', and guessed which you want...