# Read in String from stdin using pointers

Tags: c

**C pointer and string**

Is it possible to read in string from stdin and store in a pointer if I didn't know the dimension of the string?

Comment: Yes, you need to allocate memory dynamically. You heard about `malloc()`?

Comment: There are two ways of doing it - [easy but non-portable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38686325/335858), and hard but portable, with some limitations.

Comment: Or explicitly call the posix getline() or getdelim() functions which at least means if you build on something other than posix in the future you won't be scratching your head wondering how scanf can be broken. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html

Comment: Matteo, "if I didn't know the dimension of the string?"  --> Do you have a sane upper bound or do you want to allow the user to consume any amount of memory via your code?  How about limiting input to a few hundred characters?

Answer (score 1):

consider reading a whole line of input with fgets()

Answer (score 0):

Not only is the ultimate length of input not known at run-time, but the length of *chunks* of input coming in are not known either. However the answer is yes, it is possible to do what you have asked, but will require dynamic memory allocation using either *[malloc](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm)* or *[calloc](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_calloc.htm)* *AND* *[realloc](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_realloc.htm)*.  Using these functions in conjunction will allow you to capture the input from `stdin` without knowing beforehand how much there will be.

Refer to *[the accepted answer to this question for details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16870485/645128)*.