# fscanf stops when a new line is encountered in a file

Tags: c, scanf

I am using the following while loop to read through the lines in a file

```
 while (fscanf(fp, "%m[^\n]s", &line) == 1)
    {
        char c;
        fscanf(fp, "%c", &c);
    }
```

There are two things I noticed

1. The while loops operated perfectly unless there is a blank line in the file. 
   So if a file contains 5 lines with the second line as blank line then it exits at 
   the second line. So it wont read the lines further.
2. Using the  `fscanf(fp, "%c", &c);` to eat up the trailing newline character 
   which doesn't get taken by the earlier fscanf function

Is there any way to resolve 1 and some better alternative to 2 ?

Comment: `getline` or add leading space to the format string `" %m[^\n]s"`.

Comment: Please explain your thinking behind `"%m[^\n]s"` your expectation of what it does. This will reduce necessary guessing and allow to find potential misunderstandings.

Comment: I didn't know about %m. So this thread made me courios. According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38685724/difference-between-ms-and-s-scanf and subordinal citation http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html, the %m is a non-standard extension which automatically allocates memory for the corresponding field. However, a %m forces the user to deallocate memory himself. Therefore, please add deallocation to your code. The scanset takes all chars except \n. You should complete your format string by \n after the scanset to scan a complete line.

Comment: Questions involving extensions such as the `m` modifier should describe them or refer to documentation for them.

Answer (score 0):

You really should use `getline` for this. You could use `scanf` with something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(void)
{
        int rv;
        FILE *fp = stdin;
        char *line = NULL;
        while( (rv = fscanf(fp, "%m[^\n]", &line)) != EOF ){
                if( rv == 0 ){
                        line = "";
                }
                puts(line);
                fgetc(fp); /* Consume newline */
                if( rv ){
                        free(line);
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

But, don't.  `getline` is more widely available than `%m`, and easier to understand.  The `%m` specifier is a non-standard extension that allocates space for the data, and the caller is responsible for freeing that data.  `getline` is a posix extension that does exactly what you're trying to do (allocates space for a buffer to read a full line of text.)

Also, note that the conversion specifier is just `[`, not s, and the format string should not have the trailing `s`.

To use `getline`, you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(void)
{
        FILE *fp = stdin;
        char *line = NULL;
        size_t cap = 0;
        while( getline(&line, &cap, fp) != -1 ){
                fputs(line, stdout);
        }
        free(line);
        return 0;
}
```

Note that when using `getline`, the newline stays in the buffer, while the `scanf` method does not add that character.  Another advantage of `getline` is that you only need to free the buffer once, and it will minimize the allocations.

Comment: The question and the answer should explain the `m` modifier, as it is otherwise likely to confuse readers who are unaware of this extension.

Comment: My intention of using `%m[^\n]s` in scanf was to read till a new line is encountered. What I understand is the `m` is used to dynamically allocate strings or any length. Is that correct ? Also is getline a better way to achieve the same ? `scanf` certainly gets cryptic

Comment: @achal Yes, that is what %m does.  But `scanf` is pretty free about discarding whitespace, so it's the wrong tool for this.

Comment: How does one discover what's the correct method suitable in a particular situation. Like in this suppose I knew only about `scanf` than I should get some hints to move away from `scanf` to `getline` in man pages. But I don't see any such thing. Any suggestions how to look for appropriate methods for your current problem at hand ?

Comment: could you also give an example of `getline` in this case as I want to read lines of any length. Thanks

Comment: @achal  Edited with getline example.  I'm not really sure the best way to learn new methods!  I suppose mostly by posting on forums and browsing documentation.  That's one of life's great questions.

Comment: `getline()` also has the huge advantage that it either reads a line or it doesn't.  When `fscanf()` fails to read per the format string, the input stream is in an unknown state and there's no reliable way to recover.

Comment: I see your getline one. But what I was trying to do `is - *(lines + lineNumber - 1) = line;
        lines = realloc(lines, (lineNumber + 1) * sizeof(char **));
        lineNumber++;` inside the while loop when I was using `fscanf`. It's like I am trying to create an array of all lines of the file. So storing the whole file in `char**`

Comment: @achal That's easy enough to do.  See https://github.com/wrp/examples/blob/main/c/read-txt-into-array.c

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in your code:

- the `fscanf` format syntax for scansets does not have a trailing `s`, simply write:

  ```
  rv = fscanf(fp, "%m[^\n]", &line)
  ```
- `fscanf()` may fail to convert if there is an empty line in the input stream, for which it will return`0` without allocating anything not modifying `*line`.
- the trailing newline must be read separately, for example with `getc(fp)`.

Here is a modified version to handle these cases:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int parse_file(FILE *fp, void (*handler)(const char *p)) {
    int rv;
    char *line;

    while ((rv = fscanf(fp, "%m[^\n]", &line)) != EOF) {
        if (rv == 0) {
            handler("");
        } else {
            handler(line);
            free(line);
        }
        if (getc(fp) == EOF) /* read the pending newline */
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```